# Why does System Monitor and Nautilus give me different disk usage numbers?

Tags: 10.04, disk-usage

Ubuntu 10.4 LTS
Encrypted Hard-drive

I recently deleted about 30 GB of files from a folder on my Desktop. After restarting however, I found that, while I cannot find the files anywhere, my computer tells me that I only have 600MiB free/Available Space.

System Monitor tells me that I have 92GiB Total, 86GiB Used, 5GiB Free and 667MiB Available (using the command df confirms this)

While Disk Usage tells me when I scan the Filesystem that it is 53GiB size, with 667MiB Available.

Why are they telling me different disk usage numbers, and how do I completely erase the 30G of files so as to get more free space? 
Thanks!

Comment: Your files might still be in the Trash folder, open the Disk Usage Analizer with `gksu baobab` scan the system, and go to the folder which holds your files so you can delete them forever.

Comment: If you simply hit the `Delete` button, files aren't really deleted, but moved to another folder called Trash. If you want people's opinions on disk usage, show some evidence, don't make them rely on your word alone.

Comment: I know that I deleted them, then went to the 'Wastebasket' and deleted them permanently from there too.
Will Screenshots do?

Answer (score 3):

Similar question was posted on [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1845625):

System Monitor gives its values in [Gibibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) (no that is not a typo) whilst Nautilus/Disk Usage Monitor gives its values in Gigabytes.  Two different units giving different numbers.

As to permanent deletion - open up nautilus and look at your *wastebasket* or *trash* folder and delete the items there.

Comment: +1 Never heard of Gibibyte. Look forward to using it going forward to annoy.